# I am confused by the following:

Tags: reported-speech

Direct Speech= My brother says to me, "Don't you worry about my health."

Indirect Speech(acc. to book)= My brother forbids me from worrying about his health.

Shouldn't it simply be "tells" or "consoles" ??

Answer (score 1):

He said to me "Stay where you are!"

He told me to stay where I was.

My brother forbade me "Don't you worry about my health!"

My brother forbade me (not) to worry about his health.

My brother forbids me "Don't you worry about my health!"

My brother forbids me to worry about his health.

My brother said to me "Don't worry about my health!".

My brother told me not to worry about his health.

Answer (score 0):

***forbids me from worrying*** is plain wrong.

forbids me to worry is humorous and good-natured.

***My brother tells me not to worry about my health*** is correct.

Consolation is something offered to a person when there is something to worry about already.

***When I worry about my health, my brother tries to calm me down*** is also correct, and this, I believe, is what you were going for. I may be wrong. Nobody's perfect.

Comment: "Forbids me from worrying" sounds a *lot* more natural to me than "forbids me to worry".

Comment: @Paul: Actually, both are kind of stupid. And hardly natural-sounding. But "forbids me to worry" is at least funny.

Comment: I could absolutely imagine someone dramatically saying, "you are *forbidden* from worrying about this!" But I'm fairly certain a native AmE person would never say "you are forbidden to worry about this".

Comment: @Paul: ... with a German accent? By the way, "a native AmE person" is cute, too.

Answer (score 0):

"Forbids me from worrying" is overly formal language. It works grammatically, but is something you'd never say, and are unlikely to write. Instead something like "my brother insists that I do not worry about his health"

Also, "My brother says to me, "Don't you worry about my health."" is a little colloquial, and not something someone would necessarily say in normal speech. in this case, the you is used for emphasis - as in "don't you worry, someone else is dealing with it".

Answer (score 0):

'Forbid' is a raising verb ('I' is raised from the 'worry' clause to 'me') and the sub-verb is marked by making it infinite ('to worry'); but since 'forbid' has a negative connotation, the infinitive marker 'to' is often changed (by analogy with the preposition 'to[wards]') to the preposition 'from'.